# creating Blogs Posts in Github Repo and Next JS

Tags: github, next.js, content-management-system, blogs

I'd like to set up a separate Github repo where I can save blog post data and then call it into my Next.js website.

Is there is any possible way to do this? please help.

I tried looking at the solutions online but didn't found the one i am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with data like images and file resources by just adding them to the new GitHub repo and making it a [github page](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/creating-a-github-pages-site). Then you can access them in your NextJs by using URL of the hosted page

Comment: how can i then call that github page in nextjs?

Comment: If you have already hosted the page, containing resources, like images, then you want to display the image on your page, you will have to specify the domain of your github page inside the next.config.js [here is how](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#domains) and then you can use the link to the image in the src.